# Код, который проверяет идёт ли трансляция на твич

Tags: python

пытался сделать программу, которая будет уведомлять о трансляциях на платформе твич и проверять наличие трансляции каждые 15 секунд. Но что-то идёт не так и ничего не выводит, хотя ошибку тоже не выдает. Вот код:

```
    import requests
import time
import self

client_id = "jzkbprff40iqj646a697cyrvl0zt2m6"
def check_user():
    # 0: online,
    # 1: offline,
    # 2: not found,
    # 3: error
    url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/bratishkinoff'
    info = None
    status = 3
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, headers = {"Client-ID" : client_id}, timeout = 15)
        r.raise_for_status()
        info = r.json()
        if info['stream'] == None:
            status = 1
        else:
            status = 0
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        if e.response:
            if e.response.reason == 'Not Found' or e.response.reason == 'Unprocessable Entity':
                status = 2

    return status, info

def loopcheck():
    while True:
        status, info = self.check_user()
        if status == 0:
                print('STREAM IS LIVE!')
                time.sleep(refresh)
```

Comment: Но ведь вы в случае ошибки ничего и не выводите, всё правильно

Comment: У вас ведь даже нигде не вызывается ваша функция loopcheck